# Subline Text paste and indent windows 10

Tags: sublimetext3

Using sublime text 3 cutting and then paste and indent using Ctrl+Shift+V it doesn't do what I think it should do:

```
<div>
<div></div>
</div>

function(){
test;
}
```

The expected result should be:

```
<div>
    <div></div>
</div>

function(){
    test;
}
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how **`Paste and Indent`** works. It is intended for situations when you copy a line or lines with one indentation and paste it into a block with a different indentation. For example:

```html
<ul class="list1">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>
        <ul class="innerList">
            <li>OneA</li>
            <li>OneB</li>
|           <li>Three</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Four</li>
</ul>
```

Now, I want to copy the line where the cursor is (containing `<li>Three</li>`) from `innerList` to `list1`. If I just do copy and paste (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>), the indentation is wrong:

```html
<ul class="list1">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>
        <ul class="innerList">
            <li>OneA</li>
            <li>OneB</li>
            <li>Three</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Two</li>
|           <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
</ul>
```

However, if I do "paste and indent" (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>):

```html
<ul class="list1">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>
        <ul class="innerList">
            <li>OneA</li>
            <li>OneB</li>
            <li>Three</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Two</li>
|   <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
</ul>
```

The indentation is corrected for the current context. To do what you want to do, you'd need to use one of the many HTML and/or JS formatting plugins available on [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io). I personally use [`HTML-CSS-JS Prettify`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/HTML-CSS-JS%20Prettify), which runs on top of Node.js, but there are plenty to choose from.

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer! - I also used that plugin and changed it to prettify on save and works beautifully.

Answer (score -1):

as i remember there is  **Beautiful Html** extension well be useful for your issue

Comment: Thanks I will look into that one.. but as a standard feature of sublime surely it must work somehow.

Comment: This answer is not useful. You don't provide any links, and in any case there is no "Beautiful HTML" plugin in Package Control.